# subprocess call in python to invoke java jar files with JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, python

Example code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'temp.jar'])
```

How to specify the JAVA_OPTS in the above command? I am getting a 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread' when I use the above command and I think specifying JAVA_OPTS in the command would solve the problem.

I did specify the JAVA_OPTS in .bashrc file and it had no effect.

Comment: Your problem doesnt seem to be python related. Because it's executing your command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this, but finding how to do it in the documentation is kind of a wild goose chase.

The [`subprocess.call()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) says,

> **`subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)`**
>   The arguments shown above are merely the most common ones, described below in [Frequently Used Arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) (hence the slightly odd notation in the abbreviated signature).

Then the [Frequently Used Arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) section, says, at the very end after describing a bunch of other arguments:

> These options, along with all of the other options, are described in more detail in the [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor documentation.

Well then! The [`Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) documentation gives the full signature:

> `class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0)`

`env` is the one you want! However, if you just pass `env={'JAVA_OPTS': 'foo'}`, then that will override *all* environment variables, including stuff like `CLASSPATH`, which could break other things. So you probably want to use code like this to add a `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable for the new process execution, without setting it in the current process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import subprocess

# Make a copy of the environment    
env = dict(os.environ)
env['JAVA_OPTS'] = 'foo'
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'temp.jar'], env=env)
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to use JAVA_OPTS - just pass in some more arguments to `call()`. For example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'temp.jar', '-Xmx1024m', '-Xms256m'])
```