# Python Subprocess call to invoke java jar files with JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, python, subprocess, log4j, java-opts

I am trying to make a subprocess call from my python script to a java class built inside a jar. I am running the python code on a docker container in AWS Batch. I set the **CLASSPATH** environment variable in the Dockerfile to include the directory containing the jar file.

```
ENV CLASSPATH /path/to/dir/containing/jar/file
```

When I pass the entire command with arguments as a string to subprocess, it works fine.

```
runnable_command = "java $JAVA_OPTS " \
                   "RunCommand " \
                   "-b arg_b"

sp = subprocess.Popen(runnable_command,
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                      close_fds=True,
                      shell=True,
                      universal_newlines=True,
                      env=os.environ)

result, stderr_data = sp.communicate()
print(result)
```

But for that I had to make the variable "shell=True" which has a security risk. So I modified the variable 'shell=False" and I pass in the command and arguments as a list to the subprocess. This also works fine.

```
runnable_command = ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.x86_64/jre/bin/java", "$JAVA_OPTS", "<ClassName>"]
```

However, I am setting **JAVA_OPTS** environment variable in the Dockerfile to pass the log4j configuration file to JVM.

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/amazon/lib/log4j2.xml"
```

This is important because I want to pipe the logs from this java script to my python script.
When I add **JAVA_OPTS** to the command, it fails with the following error:

```
runnable_command = ["/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-jdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.x86_64/jre/bin/java", "$JAVA_OPTS", "<ClassName>"]
```

I am not able to pass JAVA_OPTS to the list of args in the subprocess command. It fails to find the log4j.xml file. I followed this [question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762048/subprocess-call-in-python-to-invoke-java-jar-files-with-java-opts) but it fails with the same error, even after adding the JAVA_OPTS to the **"env"** argument.

> 'Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS\n'

Also, when I pass the arguments as a list, I am not able to run 'java' but I am forced to pass the absolute path of java executable.

Can someone help me with the following questions?

1. How can i pass the log4j configuration to this java command?
2. Why am I having to pass the absolute path to java command when running subprocess with a list and not a string?

Comment: Java doesn't use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. It is used by some application server startup scripts. The shell does environment variable substitution on the command line, so when you don't use the shell no substitution is done.

Comment: @tgdavies I see, that makes sense, thank you!
So how can I pass the log4j configuration path to 'Java' command? Should I hardcode it in the subprocess command? Is that the only way?

Comment: You can look up the environment variable in Python, e.g.: runnable_command = ["/.../java", os.environ['JAVA_OPTS'], "<ClassName>"]

Comment: @tgdavies Well yes, I can do that. 

I was just hoping to find a way to not pass it from Python and that the java code would be able to figure it out.